# Recursion in Async. Calls - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a JSON output (tree structure) from the recursive async calls and have come up with below -

```
$scope.processTree = function (mData, callback) {               
            _processTree.getWebCollection(mData.url).then(
                function(_rdata){
                       // transform xml -> json             
                        var x2js = new X2JS();
                        var json = x2js.xml_str2json(_rdata);
                        //console.log("XML DATA: " + _rdata);
                        //console.log("JSON DATA: " + JSON.stringify(json));
                        var _webs = json.Envelope.Body.GetWebCollectionResponse.GetWebCollectionResult.Webs.Web;

                        // if response has [] of webs - array of objects / sites
                        if ($(_webs).length > 0 && $.isArray(_webs)) {                                  
                            $.each(_webs, function (key) {
                                // loop and build tree
                                mData.children.push({                                           
                                    name: "Site: " + _webs[key]._Title,
                                    url: _webs[key]._Url,
                                    children: []
                                });                                     
                                // recursive loop call for each site again
                                    $scope.processTree(mData.children[key]);                                        
                            });                             
                        }
                        // if response has {} of webs - single object / site                    
                        else if ($.isPlainObject(_webs)) {                                  
                                mData.children.push({                                           
                                    name: _webs._Title,
                                    url: _webs._Url,
                                    children: []
                                });                             
                        }
                        // if no response or response is null, do nothing
                        else {  

                        }   
                }, function(msg){                       
                    alert("ERROR!!! \n\nERROR DATA: " + msg[0] + " \tStatus: " + msg[1]);
                });                 
    };

function callback(mData){
  // do something - use mData, create tree html and display
}
```

The recursion gets all sites and subsites, if any for each site and stores in a variable - mData and when done, I need need to return and use this variable as JSON input to create a tree map. Each async. call returns either array of sites or single site, if any.

How can I return mData, only after the entire recursion has completed ? How to know if recursion has ended and a call can be made to desired function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern like the following using promises and angular's `$q` service, assuming `foo.getStuff(url)` returns an angular promise.

```
function getRec(url) {
    return foo.getStuff(url).then(function(data){
        var result = {} // construct your result
        var promises = [] // array of promises for recursive calls. 
        for (x in data) {
            promises.push(getRec(url).then(function(r){
                // update result with r
            }))
        }
        // wait for all recursive calls and then resolve the promise with the constructed result
        return $q.all(promises).then(function(){return result}) 
    })
}

getRec(ROOT_URL).then(callback)
```